# Quality of a quantile regression learner

Tags: regression, density-function, quantiles, quantile-regression

Given a learning algorithm that selects and trains quantile models, how do we evaluate it?

One idea is to - use the algorithm to train a model on a synthetic dataset

- with labels drawn from an analytical distribution (with known PDF), parameterized by the features
- and attempt to measure how the predicted quantile values differ from the ones computed from the analytical distribution.
- while varying the {number of examples shown, training duration, etc}

Would this work?

Thanks!!

Comment: Sounds reasonable.

Comment: In general, you could try to show that the estimator is consistent and try to figure out its convergence rate.